# Ubuntu 21.10 install stuck with lenovo Thinkpad e15 gen2 because of elan error

Tags: boot, kernel, thinkpad, elantech

When trying to install ubuntu from usb installation freezes on manufacturer logo. Safe graphics mode yeilds this error:

```
6750751 - end Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: elantech_change_report_id+0x1bf/0x1c4
```

Cant seem to find a working fix.

Any ideas?
Dor

Comment: Did you verify the ISO as being perfect?  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and most importantly the write to your installation media (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 ; this will fail if you used incorrect or older versions of ISO write programs that cannot deal with the 21.10 ISO)   https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: Ive verified the download, and used both disk creator on ubuntu and latest rufus on windows, both having same error during install attempt.

Comment: Fair enough.... If i have problems with booting a device; I tend to boot it on other boxes to verify the write (ie. a somewhat similar box & a very different one); where if it fails to boot on all devices - I blame the write to media (*about 5-8% fail in my experience*) where if it boots on others & only fails on the *first* box - it's specific to the hardware on that *first* box.

Comment: Just tested the media on another device (not the same model) with no such issue. I have read of an kernel bug with this thinkpad series, but dont know how to bypass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue:

> - In the grub boot menu choose `UEFI firmware settings`.
> - In there turn off the pad and tracker (Config -> Keyboard/Mouse -> Disable Trackpad) in the settings. (This by the way will **not** make them stop working, for some reason.)
> - Restart and install Ubuntu regularly.

Comment: What is the pad and tracker exactly? I've the same error I tried TrackPoint and TrackPad.

Answer (score -1):

The same just happened to me after upgrading from the earlier version, groovy gorilla. With a white screen of death in between. [Followed this for that.](https://youtu.be/vfpszgs6-kE)

I managed to get past by choosing an earlier kernel version for ubuntu from the Grub menu -> Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0.40-generic